# lacks IAM permision for a resource outside of my project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

In my gitlab-ci.yml I'm running a script to create a scheduler job. When I run it directly in the GCP terminal, it works succesfuly. But, when doing it with the deployment pipeline, it shows the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.scheduler.jobs.create.app-engine) PERMISSION_DENIED: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.create" for the resource "projects/{NAME OF A DIFFERENT PROJECT}/locations/us-central" (or the resource may not exist).
```

The issue here is that the resource stated in the erro is not the one where I'm deploying my app. Meaning, I'm not trying to create the Scheduler Job in that project. I was using gcloud.scheduler.jobs.create.http but it didn't work as well, because I'm trying to creat a Scheduler Job that targets a service deployed in the same App Engine app.

Comment: Please include details of what you're doing (e.g. the Gitlab YAML file) so that we may help. The error message only shows us that what you did was incorrect. I assume you're using a Service Account as the identity for the Google Cloud commands. It's possible that  `{NAME OF A DIFFERENT PROJECT}` is the project that owns that identity and the command is defaulting to the account's owning project. There is no `us-central` region.

Comment: Please share the details @DazWilkin mentioned.